# Flowrate of liquid rushing into a bucket

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow

[image: Empty bucket plunged into a large amount of liquid]

Imagine having a bucket being partially submerged into a large amount of liquid. The position of the bucket is maintained such as shown in the figure. How can we calculate the flowrate of the liquid rushing into the bucket?

Answer (score 2):

The liquid flows in from height $0$ to $h$ within the upper extension of the lateral surface (assume bucket radius $R$). For height $x$ between $0$ and $h$, the flow rate of liquid can be estimated from potential $\rho g x $ converted to kinetic $\frac{1}{2} \rho v^2$. Then we have a function velocity as height, $v(x)$.

The final step will carry the integral for $x$ from 0 to $h$ to obtain the volume flow rate $\Delta V / \Delta t$.
$$
     \frac{\Delta V}{\Delta t} = \int_0^h v(x) dA(x).
$$

The area for the surface from $x$ to $x+dx$ is $dA = 2\pi R dx$. This is how I think of the problem.

[image]